# What is the format of wildcard certificate name?

Tags: ssl, certificate, wildcard

I'm writing validation of SSL certificates and I'd like to know the format of certificate names with wildcards. From the [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818):

> Names may contain the wildcard character * which is considered to
> match any single domain name component or component fragment. E.g.,
> *.a.com matches foo.a.com but not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.

Is it possible for the wildcard character to appear in the middle of the name? Also can I use a few of them in one name?

```
hello.*.a.com
*.*.a.com
```

I understand that it may not be practically useful, but I want to know what is technically possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use the newer [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#page-27) instead of RFC 2818. This RFC make wildcard handling more clear. Essentially it means:

- Only left-most labels, i.e. `*.example.com` but not `www.*.com`. This implicitly excludes multiple wildcards like `*.*.example.com`.
- A wildcard label can be matched only against a single label, i.e. `*.example.com` will match `www.example.com` but not `sub.www.example.com`.
- If the wildcard is not the full label (i.e. `w*.example.com`) it should not occur inside IDNA labels.

That's about what is implemented in the browsers today. Apart from that you'll find more restrictions like no wildcards for top-level and second-level (i.e. no `*` or `*.com`) and sometimes more restrictions like no wildcards for `*.co.uk`.

Also have a look at [CAB Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/Baseline_Requirements_V1_3_1.pdf), section 3.2.2.6.

Comment: Unbelievable that those CAB BAseline Requirements are published as a PFD so you cannot link to any specific section. People creating web specification should publish in a web native format! When will these people learn??