# Unable to have Multi level wildcard SSL detected in Windows cert store

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard

#### Context

I work with multiple environments that are continuously created/destroyed.
The instances in these environments can be joined like that:

`<instance>.<environment>.<vpc>.domain.com`

where `<environement>` changes all the time

---

#### Certificates

I have created one self-signed certificates for each VPCs:

- `*.*.vpc0.domain.com`
- `*.*.vpc1.domain.com`
- etc

So it's multi-subdomain wildcard certificates (no sure if there is a common name for that).

---

#### Proxy

I have setup some proxy with nginx. The certificates are setup and I can join my backend services by using virtual hosting and SSL. As expected, my browser tells me that the certificate is not trusted if I call the service.

---

## My problem

Some of the backend services need to access other backend services through this kind of proxy in SSL. My problem rise with the `not trusted certificate error`.

The problem is that adding the certificate to the *Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities* doesn't solve this issue. I continue to have the error when I/service try to join a service in SSL.

---

#### Side notes

- The setup of a one level wildcard certificate works fine. For example `*.environment0.vpc0.domain.com` is detected in the windows Trusted Root and the error goes away.
- I don't want to desactivate this certificate control
- There are other solutions to achieve the same kind of design, my question focus on understanding why this 2 levels certificate is not detected when in the store

Regards

Comment: Thanks for this @steffen. So you confirm that 2 levels subdomains with wildcard doesn't exist ? I did see this post but have other informations on web telling that it exists.

Comment: a wildcard can only be in the left-most label. There is only one left-most label, so only one wildcard is possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138011/what-is-the-format-of-wildcard-certificate-name for more details. And there were various bugs in applications and libraries which have implemented this wrong.

Comment: thank you @steffen